# Delphi live template to surround selection with parentheses

Tags: delphi, live-templates

I'm trying to make a Delphi live template (in D2010) to surround a selection with ().  My current attempt looks like:

```
<code language="Delphi" delimiter="|"><![CDATA[(|selected|)]]>
```

and it almost works but puts in extra whitespace.  If I have a code line like:

```
if blah = 5 then
```

and I selected just the blah = 5 part and invoked my template I'd like it to come out like:

```
if (blah = 5) then
```

but it ends up being

```
if    (  blah = 5) then
```

Any suggestions?

Edit:  Here's the entire template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<codetemplate   xmlns="http://schemas.borland.com/Delphi/2005/codetemplates"
                version="1.0.0">
    <template name="(" surround="true" invoke="none">
        <description>
          Surround selection by parentheses
        </description>
        <author>
          Mark Ford
        </author>
        <code language="Delphi" delimiter="|"><![CDATA[(|selected|)]]>
        </code>
    </template>
</codetemplate>
```

Comment: I wasn't able to make your template work at all. Can you show the complete code?

Comment: BTW, ModelMaker Code-Explorer has such a feature already built-in. And it doesn't even need the selection in most cases.

Comment: Thanks Uwe,  I've now included the entire template.  I've been researching the template feature, but as far as I can tell this must be a bug/issue with it.  I'm looking in qualitycentral to see if anything matches.

Comment: Doesn't the autoformatter remove the extra spaces for you?

Comment: I'm having the same problem with a surround template in Delphi 2006.  When I manually invoke the template no whitespace is added, but when I use it to surround some code, the selection is automatically indented.  I haven't found a way to disable the indentation.

Comment: Although it appears that this bug has never been fixed, newer versions of Delphi include a feature called Smart Surround Keys where selecting text and typing "(" will automatically surround the text with "()".  Just a note in case it helps someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the templates.  It has been submitted as QC #21276.

http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=21276

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).